Using XLSXWRITER in Python: How insert 27 digit number in cell and display it as text not as scientific number
I'm writing an Excel using XLSXWRITER package in Python. Formats are applied to cells and this all works, except for one cell when the value assigned is a 27 digit text string (extracted from some source).
I've read How to apply format as 'Text' and 'Accounting' using xlsxwriter. It suggests to set the number format to '@', but when I try:
WSFMT_TX_REFINFO          = wb.add_format({'num_format': '@'
                                         , 'align': 'right'
                                         , 'border_color': WS_TX_BORDERCOLOR
                                         , 'right': WS_TX_BORDERSYTLE
                                         })

and write a cell with:
refdata = '001022002024080400002400105'
ws.write(wsRow, WS_COL_REF_INFO, refdata, WSFMT_TX_REFINFO)

The cell is shown as
1.041E+24

and in the editor field as
1.041002024073E+24

If I change the format specification from '@' to 0, i.e. change
WSFMT_TX_REFINFO          = wb.add_format({'num_format': '@'

to
WSFMT_TX_REFINFO          = wb.add_format({'num_format': 0

the cell is shown as
1022002024080400000000000

Note that the digits after the 14th are replaced by zeros. In the editor field it shows as
1.0220020240804E+24

What I need: The number shall be show as 27 digit string, exactly as found in refdata
Note: There are cases, where refdata may contain alphanumeric strings in some cases, besides pure 27 digit strings.
Any hint?

I use ' to convert number to text in Excel: ws.write(0, 0, '\'001022002024080400002400105'). No format applied.

When you write it as text then it would be shown as a string of numbers, so the first example should show '001022002024080400002400105' as exactly that. Only if it was converted to a number would it show as 1.041E+24

@moken Yes, it should but it doesn't.

It does for me, I tried your code for fun. You'll get a "number stored as text' error on the cell but the whole string is shown as written. The code I used is below in the answer along with the result.

@rachel I've tried this, but then the data is shown as '001022002024080400002400105, i.e. the apostrophe is shown.

The leading apostrophe is probably shown because you still set the formatting to string.  Leave it as general.

This may be a case where it is better to use write_string() instead of the more generic write().

@MarkRansom Tried with format only setting the cell border, i.e. 'num_format: '@' removed, but still the apostrophe is shown.

@jmcnamara This is it! Thanks. I wasn't aware of the write_string() method. Works great. If you'd add your comment as an answer, I could accept it.

This may be a case where it is better to use write_string() instead of the more generic write().

I ran the test with your code and the result is as shown
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

WS_TX_BORDERCOLOR = 'blue'
WS_TX_BORDERSYTLE = 1

WSFMT_TX_REFINFO = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '@',
                                  'align': 'right',
                                  'border_color': WS_TX_BORDERCOLOR,
                                  'right': WS_TX_BORDERSYTLE
                                  })

wsRow = 5
wsCol = 3
refdata = '001022002024080400002400105'
worksheet.write(wsRow, wsCol, refdata, WSFMT_TX_REFINFO)

workbook.close()

Result


Ths works for me as well. Can't see where the difference to my (more extensive) code it. Needs further investigation.
